# Spikes and valleys of ferrofluid

Tags: electromagnetism, nanoscience

I can understand that the spikes are formed because of the elongation of the ferrofluid due to the difference in forces experienced by the two ends of the particle. But I can't understand why there is an uneven pattern of the surface. All particles should be elongated by the same extent if they have the same difference in forces.

(I am only looking into the problem in magnetism and I will deal with the surface tension, gravity, van der waal's forces later. I also don't understand that why people associate Maxwells equations with this problem)